# Regex replace and split using Google SHeets formula

Tags: excel, regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I need to split the numbers and text on single cell to 2 columns

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZaQmWCx2PH6Fhn3RVW9PKpnTv0ML9zAHWzmk3789b04/copy

Please note the data is in single cell and I need to split in 2 columns as shown in the image

[image]

The expected outout is

[image]

I have tried with `=REGEXREPLACE(A796,"[0-9]","")`

Comment: Left() and right(), or mid() using find() for the first space.

Answer (score 1):

You may use 2 formula in 2 different cells for this:

Formula #1:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A4,"[[:blank:]].*","")
```

This finds first space and removes everything after that so that we have only starting numbers left in the result.

Formula #1:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A4,"[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+","")
```

This matches starting 1+ digits followed by 1+ whitespace and removes it so that we only have text after starting numbers.

[Sheet Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gb2cIbVZGpTod-lt4JrxDLRPRA29UpR6eS_3uxsEd_o/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try- `B2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),False,INDEX(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)))," ","@",1),"@")),,1))
```

`C2=`

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),False,INDEX(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)))," ","@",1),"@")),,2))
```

[image]